# Is there a good way to remove a element from a map?

Tags: python

I made an map called `mymap` where I would like to remove every element in it that is the biggest in order to find the second biggest. Is there a good way to remove the elements in the map. This is what I have done so far:

```
n = int(input())
mymap = map(int, input().split())
biggestnum  = max(mymap)
mymap.(biggestnum)
secondbiggestnum = max(mymap)
print(secondbiggestnum)
```

What would be an efficient and easy way to remove all instances of `biggestnum`?

Comment: The short answer is no, there's no way to remove an element from a `map`.  You'd need to convert it to a list, which is easy to do.  Even then, `list.remove` only removes the first occurrence of a given value.

Comment: A [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) isn't a container, instead it returns an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#iterators) which isn't something you can exactly remove elements from since it generates them iteratively. The best you can do is iterate over its values and skip those  you don't want to process.

Answer (score 0):

You've made this more complicated than it needs to be.  Just sort the list, and the biggest will be at the end.

```
mymap = list(sorted(set(map(int, input().split()))))
print('biggest',mymap[-1])
print('second',mymap[-2])
```

If you still need the original list, you'd want to separate this into two statement: one to do the `map`, and one to do the extraction.

Comment: Hmm, I see I glided over that point.  OK, I'll fix it.

Comment: But if I did do sort(), yes the biggest will be at the end but there could be multiple of the biggest number.
 For example:

If the list was 

`list = [1,5,7,8,2,8]`

. You see how if you did sort(), then there could be multiple of the biggest number in this case 8.

Answer (score 0):

`map` is a function in `python`. It takes two parameters:
`map(function, iterables)`. The first parameter is a `function` and the second is an `iterables`. The function returns a `map` class object.
You can convert the `map` object to list or set.

```
mymap = map(int, input().split())
mylist = sorted(list(set(mymap))) 
# if getting the same element as largest or second largest is not an issue
# then remove the set part and make it mylist = sorted(list(mymap)) 
print("max:", mylist[-1])
print("second max:", mylist[-2])
```

Comment: Well, `map` is actually a *class* not a function but that's just an implementation detail